# Precondition failure: attribute failed to set an initial value: 78 | iOS 13.2.2 | XCode 11.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm developing an app using SwiftUI and Combine. 
I'm facing a crash that occurs when I try to turn dark mode on/off a couple of times. 
The  log printed in console says:

```
precondition failure: attribute failed to set an initial value: 78
```

There's no valuable information available related to the origin of the crash in the stack trace.

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001ba5d9ec4 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x00000001ba4f9c00 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 192
    frame #2: 0x00000001ba449844 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 100
    frame #3: 0x00000001e4eae548 AttributeGraph`AG::precondition_failure(char const*, ...) + 188
    frame #4: 0x00000001e4e80194 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 1320
    frame #5: 0x00000001e4e80308 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::update_attribute(unsigned int, bool) + 372
    frame #6: 0x00000001e4e83874 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(unsigned int, unsigned int, AGTypeID, bool*) + 212
    frame #7: 0x00000001f0ca08d8 SwiftUI`generic specialization <SwiftUI.Color._Resolved> of SwiftUI.AnimatableAttribute.update(context: inout AttributeGraph.AttributeContext<SwiftUI.AnimatableAttribute<A>>) -> () + 492
    frame #8: 0x00000001f0bf7d80 SwiftUI`merged partial apply forwarder for generic specialization <SwiftUI.Color._Resolved> of  + 20
    frame #9: 0x00000001e4e80044 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 984
    frame #10: 0x00000001e4e80308 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::update_attribute(unsigned int, bool) + 372
    frame #11: 0x00000001e4e84ff0 AttributeGraph`AG::Subgraph::update(unsigned int) + 548
    frame #12: 0x00000001f093cde8 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.ViewGraph.(runTransaction in _D63C4EB7F2B205694B6515509E76E98B)(in: __C.AGGraphRef) -> () + 220
    frame #13: 0x00000001f093d114 SwiftUI`closure #1 (__C.AGGraphRef) -> (prefs: Swift.Bool, idealSize: Swift.Bool, outputs: SwiftUI.ViewGraph.Outputs) in SwiftUI.ViewGraph.updateOutputs(at: SwiftUI.Time) -> () + 116
    frame #14: 0x00000001f093ce9c SwiftUI`SwiftUI.ViewGraph.updateOutputs(at: SwiftUI.Time) -> () + 116
    frame #15: 0x00000001f0c5a6b8 SwiftUI`closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 () -> () in (extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.render(interval: Swift.Double, updateDisplayList: Swift.Bool) -> () + 960
    frame #16: 0x00000001f0c5a120 SwiftUI`closure #1 () -> () in (extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.render(interval: Swift.Double, updateDisplayList: Swift.Bool) -> () + 576
    frame #17: 0x00000001f0c4f9a8 SwiftUI`(extension in SwiftUI):SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.render(interval: Swift.Double, updateDisplayList: Swift.Bool) -> () + 400
    frame #18: 0x00000001f0852c30 SwiftUI`closure #1 () -> () in SwiftUI._UIHostingView.requestImmediateUpdate() -> () + 68
    frame #19: 0x00000001f084ed10 SwiftUI`reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () to @escaping @callee_unowned @convention(block) () -> () + 24
    frame #20: 0x0000000100eb97fc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    frame #21: 0x0000000100ebabd8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #22: 0x0000000100ec8c34 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1316
    frame #23: 0x00000001ba75f3a8 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    frame #24: 0x00000001ba75a39c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2004
    frame #25: 0x00000001ba7598a0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
    frame #26: 0x00000001c46b1328 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 104
    frame #27: 0x00000001be84a740 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1936
  * frame #28: 0x0000000100a1452c WForcast`main at AppDelegate.swift:12:7
    frame #29: 0x00000001ba5e4360 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

I have gone through a lot of discussion threads available online (Stackoverflow, Apple forums, etc.) but I couldn't find substantial information to understand the cause of this crash.

Most of the work being was done in HomeView class when this error started coming up. I have confirmed it by testing my code on previous commit.

Following is the view class.

```
struct HomeView: View {

    @ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: HomeViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "location")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 12, height: 12, alignment: .trailing)
                    .padding(.leading)
                Text(viewModel.model.cityFullName)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Spacer()
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 8, height: 8, alignment: .trailing)
                    .foregroundColor(viewModel.mode == .offline ? .red : .green)
                Text(viewModel.mode.rawValue)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                    .padding(.trailing)
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            List(viewModel.model.weatherDateMap) { item in
                DailyForcastView(viewModel: DailyForcastViewModel(model: item))
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my view model:

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set) var model: CityWeatherModel
    @Published private(set) var mode: AppMode = .offline

    init(model: CityWeatherModel) {
        self.model = model
    }
}
```

Following are my data models:

```
struct CityWeatherModel {
    var weatherDateMap: [WeatherDateMap]
    var city: City?

    var cityFullName: String {
        return city?.fullName ?? ""
    }
}
```

```
struct WeatherDateMap: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let date: Date
    let forcasts: [Forcast]
}

struct City: Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let country: String?

    var fullName: String {
        get {
            guard let name = self.name else { return "" }
            return name + ((country != nil) ? ", \(country ?? "")"  : "")
        }
    }
}

struct Forcast: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let dateInterval: Int?
    let date: Date?
    var weatherParticular: WeatherParticular?
    let weather: [Weather?]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dateInterval = "dt"
        case date  = "dtTxt"
        case weatherParticular = "main"
        case weather
    }
}

struct WeatherParticular: Decodable {
    var temp: Double?
    let tempMin: Double?
    let tempMax: Double?
    let pressure: Double?
    let seaLevel: Double?
    let humidity: Double?

    mutating func updateTemp(_ temprature:  Double?) {
        temp = temprature
    }
}

struct Weather: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let main: String?
    let description: String?
    let icon: String?
}
```

Following are the screenshots of the UI:

[image: Dark Mode UI]
[image: Normal Mode]

Has anyone encountered this? 
If yes, what was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: I don't see initialisation of `viewModel`, so where did you set it?

Comment: Hi Asperi, 
the viewModel is being injected from the previous view, that's SpashView. 
The splashViewModel does some stuff (an API call if network is accessible or loads offline data otherwise) and then injects the viewModel to the HomeView.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue. What did you do to solve it in the end?

Comment: It's possibly an ios bug. Have you tried on a newer version of ios 13.x?